# WIndows Azure web project

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'd just like to know if its possible to deploy a web project, that usually runs on the windows azure cloud, to a normal windows server 2008 pc for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you're trying to test - if it's just the web app, why not map a virtual directory to the folder? If you're not using any of the Azure features (eg Queues), then can run it standalone as a normal asp.net application through IIS

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no 'on premise' version of Azure and the only way you could do it is if you ran a dev environment on the server and ran the app in the Azure dev fabric.

I would suggest that for testing you should test on the cloud anyway as it is somewhat different to the local fabric.  The big advantage of testing and the cloud is that you can spin up and shut down instances whenever you need, so it only costs money while you are actually testing.  You might even be able to do most of your testing within the 'free' 25 hour allocation

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provide emulators to test a lot of the azure functionality locally including:

- Compute emulator: very nice as allows you test app with multiple instances running
- Storage Emulator: provide emulation of blob, table and queue storage
- SQL Express can be used inplace of SQL azure but you need to be aware it is a superset of  SQL Azure

The parts that arent emulated are:

- Caching Service (very annoying really)
- CDN (again a bit annoying)

So it depends on which azure services you are using as to how well you can test locally.